# Top k-best paths in HMM with k > number of hidden states

Tags: algorithm, hidden-markov-models, viterbi

I have implemented a k-best Viterbi algorithm in order to extract k-best paths through an HMM as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768335/finding-the-top-k-viterbi-paths-in-hmm). However, I get an error in case *k* is greater than the number of hidden states.

Consider the following: At the first observation at time *t*, every *k* for each state *j* is the same (i.e. all paths to that state are the same, since it's the first observation). I then want to compute the k-best paths for a state *i* at time *t+1*. In order to do that, I extract the k-best predecessor paths at time *t*. However, since all paths for each state at *t* are the same, I end up with the same best predecessor state *k* times for my state *i* (the same applies for all states at time *t+1*). This effectively results in all paths being the same path (1st-best).

As suggested in the [literature](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/handle/10012/4603), I disregarded paths that have already been taken when looking for k-best predecessor states. However, that effectively leaves me with *N* different paths at time *t*, with *N* referring to the number of hidden states. So, choosing *k* to be bigger than *N* results in an error when looking for k-best predecessor paths at time *t*.

I hope the point I am trying to make got through. Obviously, I am missing something here, but I cannot figure out what.